# Hide navigation bar when user scrolls

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

when i'm scrolling in my view the navigation bar does not dissapear and my screen looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kyGF.png). I want to hide the navigation bar when the user scrolls but i can't find something useful on the internet and i'm beginner on ios development & swiftUI. Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks! :-)

**My code:**

```
//
//  AddGoalView.swift
//  iGrow Goals
//
//  Created by George Sepetadelis on 6/9/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct AddGoalView: View {
    
    @State var title = ""
    @State var description = ""
    @State var numTarget = ""
    var units = ["Other", "Kg", "$$", "Km", "Hours", "Days", "Weeks", "%"]
    var categories = ["Career", "Finance", "Personal", "Health & Fitness", "Spirituality", "Relationships", "Projects", "Fun & Recreation"]
    var members = [""]
    @State var numUnitIndex = 0
    @State var categoryIndex = 0
    @State var numUnit = "Other"
    @State var startDate = Date()
    @State var endDate = Date()
    @State var category = "Other"
    @State var startDateString = "none"
    @State var endDateString = "none"
    @State var memberEmail = ""
    @State var membersText = "No members"
    @State var showPremiumDialog = false
    @State var showPremiumScreen = false
    @State var showStepTipsScreen = false
    @State var step1 = ""
    @State var step2 = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Goal Name: ").bold().font(.system(size: 20))
                        TextField("Enter Goal Name",text: $title).font(.system(size: 20))
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("SMART Goal: ").bold().font(.system(size: 20))
                        TextField("Enter SMART Goal",text: $description).font(.system(size: 20))
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Numerical Target: ").bold().font(.system(size: 20))
                        TextField("Enter Numerical Target",text: $numTarget).font(.system(size: 18))
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        Picker(selection: $numUnitIndex, label: Text("Numerical Unit: \(numUnit)")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< units.count) {
                                Text(self.units[$0]).tag($0).foregroundColor(.blue)
                            }
                        }.onChange(of: numUnitIndex, perform: { newValue in
                            numUnit = units[newValue]
                        })
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }.padding(.leading, 15)
                    
                    HStack {
                        DatePicker(
                            "Start Date",
                            selection: $startDate,
                            displayedComponents: [.date]
                        )
                        
                    }.padding(.leading, 15)
                    .padding(.trailing, 15)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .onChange(of: startDate) { newDate in
                        
                        let calendar = Calendar.current
                        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: newDate)
                        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: newDate)
                        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: newDate)
                        
                        startDateString = "\(day)/\(month)/\(year)"
                        
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        DatePicker(
                            "End Date",
                            selection: $endDate,
                            displayedComponents: [.date]
                        )
                        
                    }.padding(.leading, 15)
                    .padding(.trailing, 15)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .onChange(of: endDate) { newDate in
                        
                        let calendar = Calendar.current
                        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: newDate)
                        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: newDate)
                        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: newDate)
                        
                        endDateString = "\(day)/\(month)/\(year)"
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        Picker(selection: $categoryIndex, label: Text("Category: \(category)")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< categories.count) {
                                Text(self.categories[$0]).tag($0).foregroundColor(.blue)
                            }
                        }.onChange(of: categoryIndex, perform: { newValue in
                            category = categories[newValue]
                        })
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }.padding(.leading, 15)
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Add Member")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding(.leading, 15)
                    .padding(.top, 27)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Member email: ").bold()
                        TextField("Enter Member Email", text: $memberEmail).font(.system(size: 20))
                    }.padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    
                    Group {
                        
                        Text("Add member")
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 220, height: 50)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(40)
                            .padding(.top, 20)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                // add memeber after checking for premium plan
                            }.alert(isPresented:$showPremiumDialog) {
                                Alert(
                                    title: Text("You cannot share goals with other users without the premium plan"),
                                    primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Buy Premium")) {
                                        
                                        showPremiumScreen = true
                                    },
                                    secondaryButton: .cancel()
                                )
                            }
                        
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(membersText)
                                .bold()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .padding(.top, 4)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        
                        HStack {
                            
                            Text("Add Steps").bold().font(.system(size: 30))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                showStepTipsScreen = true
                            }, label: {
                                Image("help_icon")
                                    .padding(.trailing, 15)
                            }).sheet(isPresented: $showStepTipsScreen, content: {
                                StepsTipsView()
                            })
                            
                            
                            
                        }.padding(.top, 10)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Step 1: ").bold()
                            TextField("Enter Step Name", text: $step1)
                        }.padding(.leading, 15)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Step 2: ").bold()
                            TextField("Enter Step Name", text: $step2)
                        }.padding(.leading, 15)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Text("Create")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                        })
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .padding(.top, 30)
                        
                        NavigationLink("", destination: PurchasePremiumView(), isActive: $showPremiumScreen)

                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }.navigationBarHidden(true)
                
            }
            
        }.navigationTitle("Add New Goal")
        
    }
}

struct AddGoalView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddGoalView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the SwiftUI Community. So I ran the code, and I saw a few problems. I see a few mistakes and have recreated them myself.

Firstly, I'm guessing you are using a `ContentView` as the following code describes

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            AddGoalView()
        }
    }
}
```

And by doing so, if we go to your code, and scroll right down to the `.navigationTitle("Add New Goal")` section. You aren't setting the title to the `NavigationView` in your `AddGoalView`, but rather to the `NavigationView` in `ContentView`. To fix this, move your `.navigationTitle("Add New Goal")` to the `ScrollView` as shown below.

```
struct AddGoalView: View {
.
.
.
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
        .
        .
        .
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add New Goal") //<-- Here
}
```

Thereafter, get rid of the line`.navigationBarHidden(true)`

However, this will solve the problem of your scrolling issue, but you will notice the navbar that takes up more vertical space than you are used to seeing.
This is due to you stacking 2 `NavigationViews` on top of one another (1 in `ContentView`, and the other in `AddGoalView`). See the image below for an example

[image]

To fix this, you can completely remove the `NavigationView` in your `AddGoalView` view. This ought to fix your problem
The output can be seen below.

The Fixed code can be found in this [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/SEBVpdhn)

[image]

Comment: Can you please show some code to understand what you did exactly?

Comment: Yea, i think i recreated the problem you had. I've updated the code so you can understand

Comment: I've made changes to your answer and added the code to a Pastebin file so you can refer the code if you have any issues

Comment: Thanks, is working. But for some reason i can't see the back button

Comment: That's because, I'm not opening `AddGoalView` from `ContentView` in the code I sent.. You will have to make some adjustments so that you navigate from `ContentView`

Comment: I'm opening this view from an navigation link from the previews view

Comment: Let me check real quick

Comment: NavigationLink("", destination: AddGoalView(), isActive: $showNextScreen)

Comment: Could you include the code for `ContentView` into the question? Because I'm not sure how `showNextScreen` is triggered. However, the back button is shown on my UI when I use `NavigationLink(destination: AddGoalView()) {Text("Go To Next Screen")} `

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, I recommend you to get rid of this line, like previous commentator said:

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

In addition, I've noticed that you use `.navigationTitle("Add New Goal")` modifier outside the implementation of NavigationView. Replace it inside curly braces like here

```
NavigationView{ 
    ...some code ... 
       .navigationTitle("Add New Goal")
}
```